# Action Controller exception undefined method `merge' for xxx:String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing simple Reddit like site. I'm trying to add button to reporting posts. I create `report` model, using `button_to` i try to post data to `report controller` to create it but i received  `NoMethodError in ReportsController#create undefined method merge' for "post_id":String`

model/report.rb

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reporting_user, class_name: 'Author'
  has_one :post
end
```

report_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    report = Report.new(report_params)

    flash[:notice] = if report.save
                       'Raported'
                     else
                       report.errors.full_messages.join('. ')
                     end
  end

  def report_params
    params.require(:post).merge(reporting_user: current_author.id)
  end

end
```

and button in view

```
= button_to "Report", reports_path, method: :post, params: {post: post}
```

What cause that problem?

edit:

params

`=> <ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"sX0DQfM0rp97q8i16LGZfXPoSJNx15Hk4mmP35uFVh52bzVa30ei/Bxk/Bm40gnFmd2NvFEqj+Wze8ted66kig==", "post"=>"1", "controller"=>"reports", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>`

Comment: Can you please add the whole `params`? I think, the problem will be in `report_params` method, but I'd like to be specific.

Comment: I add whole params in first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with you want to use `belongs_to` and not `has_one`.

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reporting_user, class_name: 'Author'
  belongs_to :post
end
```

This correctly places the `post_id` foreign key column on `reports`. Using `has_one` places the fk column on `posts` which won't work.

And a generally superior solution would be to make reports [a nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
# /config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
  resources :reports, only: [:create]
end

# app/controller/reports_controller.rb
class ReportsController
  before_action :set_post

  # POST /posts/:post_id/reports
  def create
    @report = @post.reports.new(reporting_user: current_author)
    if @report.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Reported'
    else
      flash[:notice] = report.errors.full_messages.join('. ')
    end
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private

  def set_post 
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

This lets you simplify the button to just:

```
= button_to "Report", post_reports_path(post), method: :post
```

Since the `post_id` is part of the path we don't need to send any additional params.

If you do want to let the user pass additional info through a form in the future a better way to create/update resources with params and session data is by passing a block:

```
@report = @post.reports.new(report_params) do |r|
  r.reporting_user = current_user
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It's almost work but now i got error `can't write unknown attribute 'reporting_user_id'`

Comment: You need to ensure that your reports table has a `reporting_user_id` and `post_id` columns. If you don't you need to add them through a migration.

Answer (score 0):

[ActionController::Parameters#require](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L437) returns the value of the required key in the params.  Usually this would be an object passed back from a form.  In [this example](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) `require` would return `{name: "Francesco", age: 22, role: "admin"}` and merge would work.

Your view is sending back parameters that Rails is formatting into `{post: 'string'}`.  We would need to see your view code to determine what exactly needs to change.

Update: From the new code posted we can see that the parameter sent back is `"post"=>"1"`.  Normally we would be expecting `post: {id: 1, ...}`.

Update: The button in the view would need the `params` key updated to something ala <s>`params: {post: {id: post.id}}`</s> EDIT: I agree that `params: {report: { post_id: post}}` is a better format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in `report_params`. When you call `params.require(:post)`, it fetches :post from params -> the result is string. And you are calling `merge` on this string.

I'd recommend change in view:

```
= button_to "Report", reports_path, method: :post, params: { report: { post_id: post} }
```

then in controller:

```
def report_params
  params.require(:report).permit(:post_id).merge(reporting_user_id: current_author.id)
end
```

Note, that I changed also the naming according to conventions: model_id for id of the model, model or model itself.

Comment: When i change to `params.require(:report)...` I got ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError